# Validate response in Postman test script

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I am inserting data in postman. I want to apply validation from post method in test script. I am new to postman, I am not able to understand.

Here is the JSON.

```
{
  "firstname": "pradeep",
  "lastname": "tiwari",
  "mobile_no": 9911844349,
  "email": "pradeep@gmail.com",
  "user_type": 4,
  "password": "pradeep1",
  "confirmPassword":"pradeep1",
  "dob":"nanana",
  "u_org":25,
  "isfoundingpartner":"undifine",
  "gender":1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built in snippets for starters to validate your basic response messages. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples/

Comment: thanks for reply
I am getting a response:

{
    "result": {
        "code": 200,
        "status": true,
        "message": "User successfully registered"
    }
}

I want to show response  “Message” in “Test Results” how i do that

Comment: pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("string_you_want_to_search");
});

Just use this and print whatever result you want to print in Test.

Comment: let result = pm.response.json().result;

if(result.status === false){
    pm.test(result.message)
}
else{
     pm.test(result.message)
}



thanks for helping  @Arslan
i use this and i got what i want

Answer (score 0):

In order to carry out validation on your responses, you will first need to parse the data into a JavaScript object using below

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
```

You can use the below code to check for particular values in the response body

```
 pm.test("Verify Json values", function () { 
  pm.expect(jsonData.firstname).is.to.equal("pradeep"); 
  pm.expect(jsonData.lastname).is.to.equal("tiwari"); 
    pm.expect(jsonData.gender).is.to.equal(1); `
});
```